# Authentication failed: password does not match stored value in spring security 3.2

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security

I am using spring security 3.2  and my code is

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
 xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

 <http auto-config="true">
  <access-denied-handler error-page="/403page" />
  <intercept-url pattern="/user**" access="ROLE_USER" />
  <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
  <form-login login-page='/login' username-parameter="username"
   password-parameter="password" default-target-url="/user"
   authentication-failure-url="/login?authfailed" />
  <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" />
 </http>

 <!-- <authentication-manager> <authentication-provider> <user-service> <user 
  name="user" password="user@123" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" /> </user-service> 
  </authentication-provider> </authentication-manager> -->

 <authentication-manager>
  <authentication-provider>
   <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
    users-by-username-query="select username,password,enabled from qforma_users where username=?"
    authorities-by-username-query="select username, role from qforma_roles where username =?  " />
  </authentication-provider>
 </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>

// and login.jsp page is 

<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>Login Form | www.beingjavaguys.com</title>
</head>
<body>
 <center>




  <h2>Login Here</h2>


  <div style="text-align: center; padding: 30px;border: 1px solid green;width: 250px;">
   <form method="post" action="<c:url value='j_spring_security_check' />">

    <table>
     <tr>
      <td colspan="2" style="color: red">${message}</td>

     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>User Name:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="username" />
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Password:</td>
      <td><input type="password" name="password" />
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td> </td>
      <td><input type="submit" value="Login" />
      </td>

     </tr>
    </table>
   </form>
  </div>
 </center>
</body>
</html>
```

I am getting error as

> DEBUG o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils - Returning JDBC Connection
>   to DataSource
>       16:41:52.273 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG o.s.s.a.d.DaoAuthenticationProvider - Authentication failed: password
>   does not match stored value
>       16:41:52.273 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter - Authentication
>   request failed:
>   org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException:
>   Bad credentials
>       16:41:52.273 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter - Updated
>   SecurityContextHolder to contain null Authentication

please help me

I am giving correct username and password still it says Authentication failed: `password does not match stored value`

Comment: did u try to debug `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` ?

Comment: how can i do that . Please let me know..

Comment: hmmm... put a breakpoint in this class?

Answer (score 0):

```
//I have solved the issue actually I have used by putting trim(password) .i //am using postgres sql character (100) and it was occupying all the spaces even //though my password length is 4 characters .
<authentication-manager>
  <authentication-provider>
   <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
    users-by-username-query="select username,trim(password),enabled from qforma_users where username=?"
    authorities-by-username-query="select username, role from qforma_roles where username =?  " />
  </authentication-provider>
 </authentication-manager>
```